# Arduino WiFi Shield works only for 2 second delays?

Tags: arduino, server, wifi

I am trying to send sensor data from an Arduino UNO to my server running on a local wifi network. My server is an HTTP server run on NodeJS.

I need the Arduino to send data to the server as fast as possible as fast as a request every 100~250ms. The code from the [WiFiClientRepeating example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebClientRepeating) sends data to the server properly every second or so. If I reduce the frequency to something lower or equal to 500ms, the server does not seem to receive anything.

Are there any limitations to how many requests there can be done in a set period of time?

EDIT: I am using the official Arduino WiFi Shield.

Comment: Isn't that example showing 1 request every 10 seconds? Also, which version of NodeJs are you using?

Comment: I have reduced the postingInterval to 500ms for my case. Currently I am using version 0.10.36. Has anything changed to the http server in a later version?

Comment: Try setting http.globalAgent.maxSockets to something higher than the default 5. This was changed to Infinity in v0.12.x. Also, it appears like your opening and closing connections for every request, how about you try sending more than one request while the connect is open. Perhaps a 'keep-alive' rather than 'close'.

Comment: On second thought, you're only running a nodejs server. So you may instead be closing the connection on the Arduino faster than you are able to transmit the data. Can you try keeping the connection alive, using 'keep-alive' and remove the conn.close().

Comment: @Yousef What do you mean by 'remove the conn.close()'? There is nothing like that on the example (or am I missing something?). Also how do I use keep-alive? It is not just by adding keep -alive on the header right?

Comment: Sorry, in the example the "client.stop()" is closing the socket, but what I'm recommend you try is removing this and instead attempt to keep the socket open and just send additional data. Read into the 'keep-alive' header value, which basically singles to the server that the tcp connection should remain open.  It'd be easier if you provided some sample code. Something similar to this: https://gist.github.com/janajri/acd97e1d6d41482b43c0

Comment: After a good long search I came up to the conclusion that the WiFi Shield firmware has a limitation and is currently not that great for fast requests (link inc later in the day).